# Disable hover on IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, hover, css-transitions

Is there a way to disable a hover effect only in IE? I know I can disable the transition property with `"-ms-transition-property: none !important;"` and that is working fine but I would like it if there was no hover effect at all in IE. The reason i want to do that is because I have an element that has a `"transform: scale(1.05)"` on Chrome and it looks great, but the transitios looks terrible in IE, I just don't want to remove it everywhere because of IE.

Comment: How is your page designed? Could you please share related code so that I could reproduce your issue and find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a CSS class and put the transform property into it, then using JQuery to check whether the browser is IE browser, then if the browser is IE browser, using the addclass method to add the related CSS style, else using the removeclass method to remove the CSS style from the elements.

please refer to the following sample:

Html code:

```
<body class="gethover">
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS code:

```
<style>
    .box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 200px auto;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
        position: relative;
    }

    .gethover .box:hover {
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }

</style>
```

JQuery code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if (!!window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window) {
            $('body').removeClass('gethover');
        }
        else {
            $('body').addClass('gethover');
        }
    });
</script>
```